# No execution when javafx button pressed

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, javafx-8

My issue I am having is that when i click on my login in button it does nothing. There is no exceptions thrown and the try - catch doesnt seem to catch any errors/exceptions. Been looking through threads and have not found anything that works.

I have added print statements throught out the code and it seems that is stops right at the start of the first try block, also added a stackTrace in both catch blocks and nothing

```
void getLoginAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, Exception {
        String username = tfUsername.getText();
        String password = tfPassword.getText();
        loggingUsers.setUserName(username);
        loggingUsers.setPassword(password);

        FileHandler userFh = new FileHandler("UserLog.txt", true);
        SimpleFormatter sf = new SimpleFormatter();
        userFh.setFormatter(sf);
        uLog.addHandler(userFh);
        uLog.setLevel(Level.INFO);

        try {
            ObservableList<User> loginInfo = DatabaseMan.getActiveUsers();

            loginInfo.forEach((u) -> {
                try {
                    assert loggingUsers.getUserName().equals(u.getUserName()) && loggingUsers.getPassword().equals(u.getPassword()) : "Incorrect login info!";
                    loggingUsers.setUserId(u.getUserId());
                    try {
                        Appointment upcomingAppt = DatabaseAppointments.getUpcomingAppt();
                        if (!(upcomingAppt.getAppointmentId() == 0)) {
                            Alert apptAlert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                            apptAlert.setTitle("Upcoming Appointment Reminder");
                            apptAlert.setHeaderText("You have an upcoming appointment!");
                            apptAlert.setContentText("You have an appointment scheduled" 
                                    + "\non " + upcomingAppt.getStart().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL))
                                    + "\nat " + upcomingAppt.getStart().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.FULL))
                                    + " with client " + upcomingAppt.getCustomer().getCustomerName() + ".");
                            apptAlert.showAndWait();
                            if (apptAlert.getResult() == ButtonType.OK) {
                                userLog.log(Level.INFO, "User: {0} logged in.", loggingUsers.getUserName());
                                Stage loginStage = (Stage) btnLogin.getScene().getWindow();
                                loginStage.close();
                                FXMLLoader apptCalLoader = new FXMLLoader(AppointmentCalendarController.class.getResource("MainAppointment.fxml"));
                                Parent calScreen = calLoader.load();
                                Scene calScene = new Scene(calScreen);
                                Stage calStage = new Stage();
                                calStage.setTitle("Appointment Calendar");
                                calStage.setScene(apptCalScene);
                                calStage.show();
                            }
                            else {
                                apptAlert.close();
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            userLog.log(Level.INFO, "User: {0} logged in.", loggingUsers.getUserName());
                            FXMLLoader apptCalLoader = new FXMLLoader(AppointmentCalendarController.class.getResource("MainAppointment.fxml"));
                            Parent calScreen = calLoader.load();
                            Scene calScene = new Scenec(calScreen);
                            Stage calStage = new Stage();
                            calStage.setTitle("Appointment Calendar");
                            calStage.setScene(apptCalScene);
                            calStage.show();
                            Stage loginStage = (Stage) btnLogin.getScene().getWindow();
                            loginStage.close();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                catch (AssertionError e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    this.lblAlert.setText(this.rb.getString("lblErrorAlert") + ".");
                    this.lblAlert.setTextFill(Paint.valueOf("RED"));
                    userLog.log(Level.WARNING, "Invalid credentials entered! User: {0}", loggingUsers.getUserName());
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

no error messages and nothing happens when button is pressed

Comment: I assume that code inside getLoginAction() method is executed when button is clicked. Please provide code handling execution of button clicked event insetad of the method body.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: How is that method added as event handler? If it's via fxml, you may be missing a `@FXML` annotation... (Or the wrong `ActionEvent` may be imported - who knows...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We gave up on the ActionEvent tagged onto our Button Clicks
Here is how we name our Action Events and a code example
[image: Declare On Action]
The screen shot is from Scene Builder

```
    @FXML
private void onBack() throws IOException{
    stage = (Stage)childTVPane.getScene().getWindow();// pane you are ON
    paneStart = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("start.fxml"));// pane you are GOING TO
    Scene scene = new Scene(paneStart);// pane you are GOING TO
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("diary.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Diary"); 
    stage.show();
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.centerOnScreen(); 
}
```

Enjoy and Welcome to SO

Comment: I have a question why remove the action event. With doing that I will just have to go to the initialize method and assign the action there?

Comment: @NewVegasProgrammer If you notice my code does not need to initialize or assign any action. You are just using a term for OnAction  in our case onBack() The syntax is just easier to read and works